# Pushing Object in array after async code return empty array but console log prints object

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, async-await, promise

I am trying to push an Object to Array. The CSV Stream is passed to the parseCSV Function, CSVStream is stream received from GetObjectCommand aws-sdk/client-s3.

The ParseCSV function reads the CSV row line by line, makes a call to DynamoDB and gets an attribute, add the new attribute to data object and pushes the data to result array.

The issue is while trying to push the data to result array it's returning empty array but the console.log statement return the complete object line by line for the rows.
Also, in terminal, the array is printed first then console statements are printed. I am not able to understand even after using aysnc await why I am encountering it.

Terminal Output :

```
[ ] 
{
   name: "john",
   UserID: "1",
   URI: "4534asas8as8as/sample.doc"
}
```

```js
const parseCSV = (stream, ID1, ID2) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let results = [];

        stream
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', async (data) => {
                const {ID3, ID4} = data;
                const URI = await DDBDocumentClient.send(
                    new GetCommand({
                        TableName: process.env.DB,
                        Key: {
                            PK: `ORGID${ID1}#USERID${ID2}`,
                            SK: `PRODUCTID${ID3}#BATCHID${ID4}`,
                        },
                        AttributesToGet: ['URI'],
                    })
                );
                data.URI = URI.Item.URI;
                console.log(data);
                results.push(data);
            })
            .on('error', (err) => reject(err))
            .on('end', async () => resolve(results));
    });
};
```

I looked at some answers related to it, but not able to understand. Please help out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please add the code that is logging the array, it seems you haven't shown that?

Comment: I just called the function parseCSV with array, and logging the returned array. Are you asking for that part ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `stream` process triggers `end` before `DDBDocumentClient.send` done, so the `new Promise(` resolves with an empty array.

Just read data from the stream at first then query on dynamoDB

```
const parseCSV = async (stream, ID1, ID2) => { // become async function
  // get user from csv
  const users = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const result = [];

    stream
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', async (data) => {
        result.push(data);
      })
      .on('error', reject)
      .on('end', () => resolve(result));
  });

  const uriUsers = [];
  for (const user of users) {
    const { ID3, ID4 } = user; // Are you sure ID3, ID4 are existed???
    const { Item } = await DDBDocumentClient.send(
      new GetCommand({
        TableName: process.env.DB,
        Key: {
          PK: `ORGID${ID1}#USERID${ID2}`,
          SK: `PRODUCTID${ID3}#BATCHID${ID4}`,
        },
        AttributesToGet: ['URI'],
      })
    );

    uriUsers.push({
      ...user,
      URI: Item.URL,
    });

  }

  console.log(uriUsers);

  return uriUsers;
}
```

Comment: Sorry My Bad. Actually Multiple DB calls are because PK is fixed but SK is different, I am getting ID3, ID4 at each data item and fetching data from DB each time.